# Overflow in Table TD width relative width

Tags: html, css, html-table, overflow

I am struggling with this problem for quite a while now and can't find a proper solution to my problem.

**What I have:**

```
<div style="width:150px; border:1px solid #000;overflow: auto;">
    <div>SOME TEXT</div>
    <table style="width:100%; border:1px solid #0F0;">
        <tr>
            <td>HEAD1</td>
            <td>HEAD2</td>
            <td>HEAD3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
                <div style="overflow: auto; border:1px solid #F00;">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <td>HEAD</td>
                            <td>HEAD</td>
                            <td>HEAD</td>
                            <td>HEAD</td>
                            <td>HEAD</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>QQQQ</td>
                            <td>QQQQ</td>
                            <td>QQQQ</td>
                            <td>QQQQ</td>
                            <td>QQQQ</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/37ExS/

**Explanation:**

The outer div represents my content wrapper with a fixed with, which contains some other divs and a table with data.
Inside of the data table is a row, which contains another table with detailed data in reference to the row above it.

**What I want:**

The table cell, which currently has a colspan of "3", containing the detail table should have it's overflowing content creating a scrollbar. Which is why I wrapped the content in another div, but it seems like the div's width is determined by it's content, rather than by it's parents (TD) width. setting a fixed width for the inner div works, but I want it dynamically, since I really don't know the width of the content wrapper.

I hope that was understandable.

**UPDATE:**

This is how it should behave:
http://jsfiddle.net/eRA33/

I could use that and be fine about it, but I really don't know the cross-browser support and it looks a bit hacky to me, would be nice, if someone has a nicer way of doing that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you can't use the overflow property on the table element. A nicer way of doing it (in my opinion), is to add `tbody` tags and set them as `display: block`. This lets them scroll. This also avoids using a bunch of wrapper divs.

Don't worry about using table-layout; it's well supported.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout

Here's a small fiddle to demonstrate. I put your styles in the style section, as it was easier for me to work that way :)

http://jsfiddle.net/eRA33/2/

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div>SOME TEXT</div>

<table class="table-scroll table-data">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>HEAD1</td>
            <td>HEAD2</td>
            <td>HEAD3</td>
            <td>HEAD4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4">
                <table class="table-scroll table-detail">
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>HEAD</td>
                            <td>HEAD</td>
                            <td>HEAD</td>
                            <td>HEAD</td>
                            <td>HEAD</td>
                            <td>HEAD</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>QQQQ</td>
                            <td>QQQQ</td>
                            <td>QQQQ</td>
                            <td>QQQQ</td>
                            <td>QQQQ</td>
                            <td>QQQQ</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.wrapper {
    width:180px;
    border:1px solid #000;
}

.table-scroll {
    width:100%;
    table-layout: fixed;
}

.table-scroll tbody {
    display:block;
    overflow:scroll;
}

.table-data {
    border:1px solid #0F0;   
}
.table-detail {
    border:1px solid #F00;
}
```